# Adding "Question {Number}" to top of merged pdf documents

Tags: python, pypdf, xlwings

As a great surprise to myself I have managed to write some code in python that merges some pdf files together from file paths contained in an excel document. Each pdf represents a question and the merged document creates a worksheet of problems for students. What is missing at the moment is the ability to put "Question [number]" at the top of each pdf document. The question number will match the page number i.e Question 10 is page 10. Here is my current code...

```
import xlwings as xw
import from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger, PdfReader
import openpyxl as op

wbxl = xw.Book('demo.xlsm')
get_links = wbxl.sheets['Sheet1'].range('C2:C5').value
filenames = []

for file in get_links:
    if file is not None:
        filenames.append(file)

merged_pdf = PdfMerger()
for i in range(len(filenames)):
    merged_pdf.append(filenames[i], 'rb')

output_name = wbxl.sheets['Sheet1'].range('C7').value
merged_pdf.write(output_name + ".pdf")
```

Is there a way to add on a few lines to get these question numbers on the pages? Also these pdfs contain images and tables etc so converting to word and using docx python libraries might not work

Comment: You should delete the openpyxl tag from your question

Comment: PyPDF2 renamed itself to pypdf. Use pypdf, as PyPDF2 is deprecated (I'm the maintainer of both)

Comment: @MartinThoma Wow great! thanks for that; I did wonder why I was having some problems with PyPDF2 things. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Using PyMuPDF makes merging PDFs and writing text to pages easy.

From your code it wasn't clear to me whether each PDF has just one page - the following code reads each PDF from `filenames`, puts a header line on each of its pages, and then appends the thus modified PDF to the desired output PDF.

```py
import fitz  # import package PyMuPDF
# assuming 'filenames' = list of PDF file names.
outpdf = fitz.open()  # output PDF

for i, filename in enumerate(filenames, start=1):
    src = fitz.open(filename)  # open an input file
    page_count = src.page_count  # its number of pages
    for page in src:  # iterate through input pages
        # put a centered header on each page, half an inch from top
        rect = fitz.Rect(0, 36, page.rect.width, 72)
        page.insert_textbox(
            rect,
            f"Question {i}, page {page.number} of {page_count}",
            align=fitz.TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER,
        )
    # input PDF modified, now save to memory, re-open as input and append
    pdfbytes = src.tobytes()  # save to memory as bytes object
    src = fitz.open("pdf", pdfbytes)  # re-open
    outpdf.insert_pdf(src)  # append input PDF

outpdf.save("output.pdf", garbage=3, deflate=True)
```

The `Page` method `insert_textbox` has more parameters to set text color, choosing the desired font (default is Helvetica / Arial), font size, etc.

Rectangles in PyMuPDF are defined as `fitz.Rect(left, top, right, bottom)`. So the rectangle above starts 36 points from page top (72 points = 1 inch) and has a height of 36 points (0.5 inch). The default font size is 11 points, so only about half of the height is actually used - change all this as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jorj for the guidance and ideas. I modified it because it wasn't quite producing what was needed. I post my code below that worked. The clean contents bit was really useful as it made the text look the same on each page:

```
def insert_qu_numbers(document):
qu_numbers = fitz.open(document)
counter = 0
for page in qu_numbers:
    page.clean_contents()
    counter += 1
    text = f"Question {counter}"
    text_length = fitz.get_text_length(text, fontname= "times-roman")
    print(text_length)
    rect_x0 = 70
    rect_y0 = 50
    rect_x1 = rect_x0 + text_length + 35
    rect_y1 = rect_y0 + 40

    rect = fitz.Rect(rect_x0, rect_y0, rect_x1, rect_y1)
    page.insert_textbox(rect, text, fontsize = 16, fontname = "times-roman", align = 0)
```